# android screen recorder code example

Tags: android, video, record, video-capture

i would like to record the current screen as video file.

Can any one help me how do i record android device screen as video using my android app or android code.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25616026/screen-recorder-in-android-programmactically-not-screen-shots/33326957#33326957